# Read() in pipe unix

Tags: unix, pipe, wait

If we have 20 bytes in a pipe and we read 30 bytes. Will the read wait for the missing 10 bytes or will continue?

Answer (score 0):

If the writing file descriptor is closed, the POSIX `read` call will be non-blocking and returns 0 to indicate end-of-file.

If this is not the case, it depends on your pipe file descriptor. In general, the `O_NONBLOCK` file status flag determines the behaviour when reading more data than available in the buffer of a open file descriptor, as it decides if the descriptor is in blocking mode, [per POSIX `fcntl.h` header](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/fcntl.h.html):

> O_NONBLOCK
>
> Non-blocking mode.

If you set this flag on the file descriptor (for pipes using the `fcntl` function), the pipe is non-blocking and blocking otherwise.

This is more formally specified in [the `read` POSIX function specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, *read()* shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file.
> - If some process has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is set, *read()* shall return -1 and set errno to [EAGAIN].
> - If some process has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is clear, *read()* shall block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe open for writing.

So the answer on your specific question is: it depends.